# diffration pattern fft crystallography

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, signal-processing, fft

I want to inverse(fft) my diffraction pattern.

[image]

But the output is always a black picture with no error.

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import numpy as np

A = cv2.imread(“picture.png“, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
B = np.fft.ifftshift(A)
C = np.fft.ifft2(B)
cv2_imshow(C)
```

Is something with my code wrong?

I actually have no idea what i can do about it. Can someone help me please.

Comment: This is the magnitude of white rectangle image on black background. To invert it, you would need the phase image.  Alterately, knowing this pattern is the fft of rectangle, one can determine the size of the rectangle from the number of elements in the pattern in each dimension and the dimensions of the image.

Comment: Do you know which command or function I need to get my inverse pattern?

Comment: You need the corresponding phase image to convert back to spatial domain to get the pattern.  But as I said above your image represents a rectangle (or possibly square) on a black background. The pattern and image dimensions will tell you the dimensions of the rectangle

Comment: Ok I try, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what kind of result you were expecting, viewed as an image. But it is not black.

I don't know what that `cv2_imshow` from google collab does. And especially how does it scales "vertically" the data. Does it expect to spawn from 0 to 1, or from 0 to 255, or does it "autoscale" it...
So maybe that is why it appears black. But just print the data, and you'll see that it is not all 0.

Also, another source of problem is that C is complex. So how that `cv2_imshow` deals with image of complex numbers, I don't know.

Here are the real and imaginary part of C

[image]

[image]

(viewed with matplotlib and colormap `prism` that has fast varying colors, to see slow gradient)

So again, I don't know google collab's `cv2_imshow`. But my guess is that it is just a viewing problem. Either it can't deal with complex number. Or it use a fixed range colormap and can't deal with the actual range of data. Or the colormap has a too smooth gradient, so you didn't notice the slight variations in the corner.
But data is not all-0.

Comment: The cv2_imshow was a recommendation from google colab. So i replace cv2.imshow with cv2.imshow

Comment: Should i fix the complex problem with np.abs()?

Comment: Well, I don't know if it is a problem, and if it would fix it. There are many functions that map a complex number to a real number. `np.abs` (modulus) is one of them. But so are `np.real` (real part), `np.imag` (imaginary part), and `np.angle` (argument). Just to mention the obvious one. All of them, sure, would "solve" the "problem" of `C` being complex. But it doesn't mean that it make sense. It depends on what information you expect to extract from `C`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to inverse my diffraction pattern with ifft2.

Comment: Actually the result should be a image of a rectangle but it doesn’t work.

Comment: Well you can't, since your original image is not a fft. It is just the amplitude part. What you are trying to do would be the same as trying to build back a soundtrack from a histogram of frequencies. That is not enough. You need phase also.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern looks like the spectrum (log of magnitude) of the FFT of a rectangle in the spatial domain. To properly invert it back to the spatial domain in Python/OpenCV, you need the corresponding magnitude and phase image.

However, as we know it is a rectangle, its properties are well known. The pattern looks like an abs of the Sinc(x,y) function in each dimension (See https://www.projectrhea.org/rhea/index.php/2D_Signals-Rect(x,y)). The spacing between center and first dark lobe (zero crossing of non-abs Sinc), plus the dimensions of the image determine the size of the rectangle as follows.

If rx=rectangle width and rh=rectangle height and sy=spacing of first two lobes in y and sx=spacing of first two lobes in x (usually the FFT has dimensions swapped with the spatial domain), and the image dimensions are W and H, then if

Sinc(pi*x) = sin(pi*x)/(pi*x) has roots (zeros) at integers

So Sinc(pi*x*sy/W)*Sinc(pi*y*sx/H) has first root at rx, ry at

rx=W/sy and ry=H/sx (and other roots at integer multiples)

In this image, we have sx=sy=16 (approx) and W=H=512, so

rx=ry=512/16=32

So if we construct a white rectangle on black background of dimensions 32x32 centered in a 512x512 image and do the FFT and look at the spectrum, we can see if the pattern matches.

I do this easily in Imagemagick (but it should be repeatable in Python/OpenCV).

```
convert -size 512x512 xc:black -fill xc:white \
-draw "translate 256,256 rectangle -16,-16 +16,+16" -alpha off +write rectangle.png \
-fft +delete -evaluate log 10000 -auto-level x.png
```

Here is the image of the rectangle (created in first two lines of code):

[image]

Here is its spectrum (stretched to full dynamic range):
(Third line gets FFT magnitude and phase and deletes the phase, then takes the scaled log to form the spectrum)

[image]

So you can see that the number of lobes in each dimension is the same, which confirms the dimensions of the rectangle (to within a pixel or so, as blink comparison of spectra images shows a slightly different spacing).

I am not sure why your image has a dark dot in the center.

Normally with forward normalization, the center pixel in magnitude would be the mean of the input image. However once we stretch it to full dynamic range or brighten it in any way such as taking the log, we lose the ability to determine the mean and as such the brightness of the rectangle, which would be

mean = (32x32)xbrightness of center pixel of magnitude/(512x512)

But we do not have the magnitude. The image looks like only a brightened spectrum or brightened magnitude. So we cannot determine the actual brightness of the rectangle.

**ADDITION**

Here is a Python/OpenCV equivalent:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# read the image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('spectrum_unknown.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]
centx = round(ww/2)
centy = round(hh/2)

# Abs of sinc(pi*x) has roots at integers, so first root at 1
# Abs of sinc(pi*i*x*sy/W) has first root at rx=W/sy and similarly ry=H/sx
# where sx=sy=16 (approx)
rx = ww/16
ry = hh/16

#So create a white square of size rx,ry centered on a black background
square = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.uint8)
square[centy-16:centy+16, centx-16:centx+16] = 255

# convert square to floats and do dft saving as complex output
dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(square), flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)

# apply shift of origin from upper left corner to center of image
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)

# extract magnitude and phase images
mag, phase = cv2.cartToPolar(dft_shift[:,:,0], dft_shift[:,:,1])

# get spectrum for viewing only
spec = np.log((mag+1)/255) / 30

# convert from float in range 0-1 to uint8 in range 0-255
spec = (255*spec).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# stretch spectrum to full dynamic range
spec_stretch = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(spec, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("square_image.png", square)
cv2.imwrite("spectrum_unknown_spectrum_opencv2.png", spec)
cv2.imwrite("spectrum_unknown_spectrum_stretch_opencv2.png", spec_stretch)

# show results
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("square", square)
cv2.imshow("spectrum_of_square_image", spec)
cv2.imshow("spectrum_of_square_image_stretched", spec_stretch)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Square image:

[image]

Spectrum Image:

[image]

Spectrum Image stretched to full dynamic range:

[image]

Comment: It is customary to up-vote an answer that is helpful.

Comment: If you need help converting to Python/OpenCV, let me know.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can’t up-vote any comment here. Because I need at least 15 reputations so that I can vote.